# UIScrollView with multiple AVPlayerViews

Tags: objective-c, scrollview, avplayer

i need your help. I want to create a horizontal `ScrollView` with some `AVPlayers`. I tried this `ScrollView` with some pictures and it works. The problem now is that i can scroll due the `View`, but all the `AVPlayerViews` are at the same position, so i just can see the last-loaded video and all the other scroll positions are blank.

This is the source of my class:

```
@implementation VPVideoScroller

const CGFloat kScrollObjHeight  = 748.0;
const CGFloat kScrollObjWidth   = 1024.0;

NSUInteger numImages = 0;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    numImages = _pictureArray.count;
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];

    // 1. setup the scrollview for multiple images and add it to the view controller
    self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    // load all the images from our bundle and add them to the scroll view
    NSUInteger i;
    for (i = 1; i <= numImages; i++)
    {

        if (i<3) {

        /*
        //------------
        MPMediaItem *item = [self.pictureArray objectAtIndex:(i-1)];

        NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
        */

        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:self.currentURL];

        AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

        //------------
            UIView *imageView = [[UIView alloc] init];

        AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
        [player play];
        /*
        UIImage *image = [self.pictureArray objectAtIndex:(i-1)];

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        */

        // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"


        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
        rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
        imageView.frame = rect;
        imageView.tag = i;  // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        [imageView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
        playerLayer.frame = imageView.layer.bounds; 

        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        }
    }

    [self layoutScrollImages];  // now place the photos in serial layout within the scrollview
}

- (void)layoutScrollImages
{
    UIImageView *view = nil;
    NSArray *subviews = [self.scrollView subviews];

    // reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
    CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
    for (view in subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
        {
            CGRect frame = view.frame;
            frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
            view.frame = frame;

            curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
        }
    }

    // set the content size so it can be scrollable
    //[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((numImages * kScrollObjWidth), [self.scrollView bounds].size.height)];

    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((numImages * kScrollObjWidth), kScrollObjHeight)];


}
```

The `pictureArray` contains an `Array` of URLs, but they are all the same. So `AVPlayers` should show all the same video.

[image: UIScrollView]

Thank you in advance. Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution :) The problem was in the method `-(void)layoutScrollImages`. Of course there i don't use `UIImageViews`. This need to be changed to `UIView`, because the `AVPlayer` players are in `UIVIew`.

This version of the method is working.

```
- (void)layoutScrollImages
{
    UIView *view = nil;
    NSArray *subviews = [self.scrollView subviews];

    // reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
    CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
    for (view in subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] && view.tag > 0)
        {
            CGRect frame = view.frame;
            frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
            view.frame = frame;

            curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
        }
    }

    // set the content size so it can be scrollable
    //[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((numImages * kScrollObjWidth), [self.scrollView bounds].size.height)];

    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((numImages * kScrollObjWidth), kScrollObjHeight)];

}
```

I hope this helps also other people.